# Hybris CronJob - export to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, sap-commerce-cloud

I have to create a cronjob to export Hybris data to AWS S3.
Has anyone done something like this before. Is it possible?
Any online links where it is explained

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and not very complicated. You can use existing [S3 libraries](https://aws.amazon.com/de/sdk-for-java/) to achieve this. You can check this [blog post](https://medium.com/@gazal.k/using-amazon-s3-for-hybris-commerce-media-2f803fc65e5a) for implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is helpful 
Does the same process apply for uploading exported (data like product) CSV files to AWS S3

Comment: @Nosidec Yeah, the AWS S3 libraries let to connect to S3 and upload to it. It doesn't matter what file, as long as S3 will accept it.